# Getting ArrayList<Spanned> from OnActivityResult function saved inside Intent

Tags: android, android-activity

I am currently working on an android project and I have an activity that is started using the `startActivityForResult()` function.

Within this activity I have an ArrayList and I create an Internet and then set the result as the intent, as in the following code.

```
private void getSearchData()
    {
        ArrayList<Spanned> passwords = null;
        String searchTerm = txtSearch.getText().toString();
        GetSearchResults search = new GetSearchResults(this, searchTerm);
        if (rdoApp.isChecked())
        {
            passwords = search.getData(SearchType.App);
        }
        else if (rdoName.isChecked())
        {
            passwords = search.getData(SearchType.Name);
        }
        else if (rdoUsername.isChecked())
        {
            passwords = search.getData(SearchType.Username);
        }

        Intent intent = new Intent();
        intent.putExtra("searchResults", passwords);
        setResult(1, intent);
        finish();
    }
```

In the first activity in the function `OnActivityResult` I then want to get the ArrayList so that I can process the data. I have the following code so far.

```
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data)
{
    common.showToastMessage("Result received", Toast.LENGTH_LONG);
    Bundle bundle = data.getExtras();

}
```

I have no idea where to go from here.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I've managed to find a way, it is thank to @Jan Gerlinger answer pointed me in the correct direction but I've found how to do it.

In the activity where I am setting the result I have the following code

```
ArrayList<Spanned> passwords = search.getResult();
Intent intent = new Intent();
Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
bundle.putSerializable("passwords", passwords);
intent.putExtras(bundle);
setResult(1, intent);
finish();
```

In the activity for inside the OnActivityResult function I have the following

```
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data)
{
common.showToastMessage("Result received", Toast.LENGTH_LONG);
Bundle bundle = data.getExtras();
ArrayList<Spanned> passwords = (ArrayList<Spanned>) bundle.getSerializable("passwords");
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
intent.putExtra("searchResults", passwords);
```

here uses the [`putExtra(String name, Serializable value)`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html#putExtra%28java.lang.String,%20java.io.Serializable%29) method. So you can use [`getSerializableExtra(String name)`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html#getSerializableExtra%28java.lang.String%29) to get it back:

```
ArrayList<Spanned> passwords = (ArrayList<Spanned>) data.getSerializableExtra("searchResults");
```

Depending on the type of your [Spanned](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/text/Spanned.html) objects and if they do implement `Serializable`, this may however throw Exceptions as `Spanned` does not implement `Serializable` directly.