# Passing ArrayList<Object> back to main Activity (Android)

Tags: java, android, arraylist, onactivityresult

I have an ArrayList< Object> where the Object is an instance of a class I made. I want to pass this new array list back to the main activity to put it in a navigationdrawer item.

How do I pass an ArrayList< Object> from an activity back to the main one?

I have tried the bundle.getParcelableArrayList however it tells me that "Inferred type Object for type parameter T is not within its bounds, should implement android.os.parcelable"

Here is my Code:

```
public void createPlaylist(String playlistName, ArrayList<Song> newPlaylistSongsArray) {
    Intent returnIntent = new Intent();
    Bundle b = new Bundle();
    b.putParcelableArrayList("array", (ArrayList<? extends Parcelable>) newPlaylistSongsArray);
    returnIntent.putExtra("playListName", playlistName);
    returnIntent.putExtra("array", newPlaylistSongsArray);
    setResult(Activity.RESULT_OK,returnIntent);
    finish();
}
```

And:

```
@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    if (requestCode == 1) {
        if (resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK){
            String newPlaylistName = data.getStringExtra("playListName");
            Bundle b = getIntent().getExtras();
            final ArrayList<Song> newPlaylist = b.getParcelableArrayList("array");
            Toast.makeText(MP3Player.this, "New Playlist Created", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
        if (resultCode == Activity.RESULT_CANCELED) {
            Toast.makeText(MP3Player.this, "Shit went wrong yo!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Your `Object` class needs to implement `Parcelable`. You can't send complex data, such as your own custom objects, through intents without serialising them first.

Comment: Note that you have an `ArrayList<Song>` not an `ArrayList<Object>`.

Comment: You can declare a singleton class , and add this to your class. And you can access this from any activity

Comment: @MariaGheorghe Singleton will not solve the issue here.

Comment: b85411, add an answer so i can select you as solver.  I found it here too just now: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12698555/getting-arraylistspanned-from-onactivityresult-function-saved-inside-intent

Comment: Note that the error message told you exactly what to do as well.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For the easiest way, your Song class need implement Serializable.

```
Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
bundle.putSerializable("newPlaylist", newPlaylist);
intent.putExtras(bundle);
```

in other activity:

```
Intent intent = this.getIntent();
Bundle bundle = intent.getExtras();

ArrayList<Song> newPlaylist=
               (ArrayList<Song>)bundle.getSerializable("newPlaylist");
```

Comment: I hadn't set my song class to implement serializable.